# Error With UICollectionView Sections While Accessing Cells

Tags: objective-c, uikit, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I'm writing a loop that will go through each one of my cells, and make them wiggle. (Like the deletion effect on iOS's home screen). When I do this with just one cell, it works like a charm. When I write a loop to do this, I get an odd error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'request for number of
>   items before section 2 when there are only 1 sections in the
>   collection view'

Now, when I researched this error the only information I could find was that this occurred when a user tried deleting a cell. That's not my case. (Well, yet at least. Just want to make them all wiggle first).

Here is my code:

```
#define RADIANS(degrees) ((degrees * M_PI) / 180.0)
    CGAffineTransform leftWobble = CGAffineTransformRotate(CGAffineTransformIdentity, RADIANS(-5.0));
    CGAffineTransform rightWobble = CGAffineTransformRotate(CGAffineTransformIdentity, RADIANS(5.0));

-(void)handleLongPress:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {

  int visible = self.gridView.visibleCells.count;

    for (int i = 0; i < visible; i++) {

    NSIndexPath *path = [NSIndexPath indexPathWithIndex:i];
    myCell = [self.gridView cellForItemAtIndexPath:path];

    myCell.transform = leftWobble;

    [UIView beginAnimations:@"wobble" context:(__bridge void *)(myCell)];
    [UIView setAnimationRepeatAutoreverses:YES]; // important
    [UIView setAnimationRepeatCount:10];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.25];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    [UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(wobbleEnded:finished:context:)];

    myCell.transform = rightWobble; // end here & auto-reverse

    }
  [UIView commitAnimations];

}
@end
```

Like I said, it works fine for one cell, and throws that error when I try to write a loop to do them all. Does anyone know what's wrong here?

Side note, how can I add a small delete buttons inside the upper left of the collection view cells programmatically in this loop? I'm very, very new to collection views.

Also just found out, my entire view wobbles when I side scroll, not just the cells.... Very odd.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#define RADIANS(degrees) ((degrees * M_PI) / 180.0)
CGAffineTransform leftWobble = CGAffineTransformRotate(CGAffineTransformIdentity, RADIANS(-5.0));
CGAffineTransform rightWobble = CGAffineTransformRotate(CGAffineTransformIdentity, RADIANS(5.0));

for (UICollectionView *cell in self.gridView.visibleCells) {
    cell.transform = leftWobble;
}

[UIView beginAnimations:@"wobble" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationRepeatAutoreverses:YES]; // important
[UIView setAnimationRepeatCount:10];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1.25];
[UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
[UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(wobbleEnded:finished:context:)];

for (UICollectionViewCell *cell in self.gridView.visibleCells) {
    cell.transform = rightWobble;
}
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

> how can I add a small delete buttons inside the upper left of the collection view cells programmatically in this loop?

Add delete button as `UIButton` to your cell's subviews in you custom `UICollectionViewCell` subclass, and `setHidden:NO` when needed.

> Also just found out, my entire view wobbles when I side scroll, not
>   just the cells.... Very odd.

Edited.